# RHL and LHL of $\frac{\sin([x])}{[x]}$

Tags: calculus

I've to find the limit of $\dfrac{\sin([x])}{[x]}$ at $x \to 0$. I got the LHL as $\sin(1)$. According to the book, the RHL is outside domain. So, Limit exists.
Could someone please explain how the RHL is out of domain?

P.S.: $[.]$ is Greatest Integer Function.

Comment: about which point are you trying to find L.H.L. and R.H.L.

Comment: [.] is greatest integer function ??

Comment: Oh sorry, yes [.] is GIF and at x tends to 0.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is $f(\frac12)$ ?

Comment: @an4s I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R.H.L. will have Numerator = $0$ and Denominator = $0$.
and $\cfrac 00$ is indeterminate.

Comment: It will be sin0/0. Is that equivalent to limit x->0 sinx/x which is 1.?

Comment: No, that is limitting case. X  is not equal to 0, X is tending to 0. If X is tending to 0 , then only $\cfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: I see, so sinx/x (not [.]) is discontinuous at x = 0, as RHL isn't equal to f(0)?

Comment: Yes, $\cfrac {\sin x}{x} $ is not continuous at x=0.
If you got the solution, accept the answer. 
Thanks